# Call to a member function swap() on null

Tags: laravel, stripe

Buenas es la primera vez que estoy usando Laravel Cashier con Stripe para manejar suscripciones.
Mi problema viene a la hora de cambiar el plan de la persona que se suscribe, que tanto en la documentación oficial de laravel como mis busquedas, se realiza del siguiente modo:

```
$user = auth()->user();
  //dd($user);
$user->subscription('price_1NDW34Fv7V7yZ8oEozvXmLtN')->swap('price_1NEAZ2Fv7V7yZ8oE55bHOvDN');
$user->save();
```

Pero todo el rato me devuleve:

```
Call to a member function swap() on null
```

No se que puedo hacer, o que estoy haciendo mal, alguna sugerencia??

Utilizo Laravel 10

Comment: y si tiene la suscripción a ese plan?

Comment: Hola @JulioGuerrero realmente es para que tal como se suscriben, cambie de plan automaticamente, ya que el primer pago es un importe y los demás a otro importe distinto